# htaccess rewrite for MSIE to non https

Tags: .htaccess, internet-explorer, ssl, https

I want to convert my site to SSL. The certificates etc are all in place and tests great on all browsers except early IE.

I'm trying to get around this by leaving the site as 'non-HTTPS' for those (few?) who still use IE.

I've tried several possible solutions without success - I thought this one would work but it doesn't...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*MSIE.*
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}[R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else is looking for a solution to this particular issue. After much trial & error (more error and it was a trial) i found that this works:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MSIE [6-9]" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I wanted this so that visitors who use old IE browsers could still visit the site and not be put off by Certificate error messages generated by IE